# angular scoping issue across controllers, not automatically updating the view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

So I'm having an issue with my ng-repeat in my displayCtrl. I'm able to add objects to my $scope.votes array on an ajax call as intended, but that's not being automatically updated in the view. Thoughts? Here's my script:

```
var glassCongress = angular.module('glassCongress', []).run(function($rootScope){
  $rootScope.votes = [];
}).controller('searchCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $http){
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sendstuff').on('submit',function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        url: '/search/' + $('#input').val(),
        type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json'
      }).done(function(data){
        for(var voteIndex = 0; voteIndex < data.data.length; voteIndex++){
          $rootscope.votes.push({
            "voteValue": (data.data[voteIndex].option.value)
          })
        }
      })
    })
  })
 }).controller('displayCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope){

 })
```

And here's my html:

```
<html ng-app="glassCongress">
<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js">    </script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="search" ng-controller = "searchCtrl">
<div>
  <form id='sendstuff' action='senddata' method='get'>
    <input id='input' type='text'/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
</div>
</div>
  <div id="display" ng-controller = "displayCtrl">
  <div>
     <ul>
       <li ng-repeat="vote in votes"><span>{{vote}}</span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your $.ajax call runs out of the angularjs scope. Becouse of that, anglarjs don't update the view automaticly.

There is tow possible solutions.

1 - use the [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) module. You can replace the $.ajax call by $http call. Read the doc to get more information.

2 - after change your model in ajax callback, call the method `$acope.apply()` to force angularjs update your view.

Inset use $rootScope, you should use $scope.